# Remove consecutive duplicates in a string to make the smallest string

Tags: algorithm

Given a string and the constraint of matching on >= 3 characters, how can you ensure that the result string will be as small as possible?

edit with gassa's explicitness:

E.G.
`'AAAABBBAC'`

If I remove the B's first, 
`AAAA[BBB]AC -- > AAAAAC`, then I can remove all of the A's from the resultant string and be left with:

`[AAAAA]C --> C`

`'C'`

If I just remove what is available first (the sequence of A's), I get:

`[AAAA]BBBAC -- > [BBB]AC --> AC`

`'AC'`

Comment: @ObsidianAge As I understand it, the goal is to get the shortest string in the end. Our choice is in the order of operations. In the given example, it is either `AAAA[BBB]AC` to `[AAAAA]C` to `C`, or `[AAAA]BBBAC` to `[BBB]AC` to `AC`.

Comment: One way would be to check on every candidate sequence of length k >= 3 if the resolved sequence at the (k + 1)th position on elimination increases the length of the candidate sequence to k` >= k + 1. 

If yes, 
then eliminate this sequence and perform the check again, 

Else, eliminate candidate sequence and continue.

A resolved sequence of length k implies that by using the defined operations, there can be no sequence of length k` >= k + 1 obtained.

Comment: The approach still has a few holes but might be a place to start.

Comment: I think this is a kind of combination between all possible shortenings - which each depends on previous paths - And you'd try all these paths to find the best solution.

Comment: Any constraints? like number of unique characters? number of total characters?

Comment: What is `the constraint of matching on >= 3 characters`? does that mean the number of duplicate character should be >= 3 to be removed? or it just simply means the number of the character in the input >= 3 (which doesn't make much sense here)

Comment: @PhamTrung in the proposed example 5 A got removed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: So what should be the result of this string ‘AA’? Blank or ‘AA’ ? @Yola

Comment: @PhamTrung that should be 'AA' i believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **tree** would definitely get you the shortest string(s).

**The tree solution**:

1. Define a `State` (node) for each current `string Input` and all its removable sub-strings' `int[] Indexes`.
2. Create the tree: For each `int index` create another `State` and add it to the parent state `State[] Children`.
3. A `State` with no possible removable sub-strings has no children `Children = null`.
4. Get all Descendants `State[]` of your root `State`. Order them by their shortest `string Input`. And that is/are your answer(s).

**Test cases**:

```cs
string result = FindShortest("AAAABBBAC");      // AC
string result2 = FindShortest("AABBAAAC");      // AABBC
string result3 = FindShortest("BAABCCCBBA");    // B
```

**The Code**:

*Note: Of-course everyone is welcome to enhance the following code in terms of performance and/or fixing any bug.*

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result = FindShortest("AAAABBBAC");      // AC
        string result2 = FindShortest("AABBAAAC");      // AABBC
        string result3 = FindShortest("BAABCCCBBA");    // B
    }

    // finds the FIRST shortest string for a given input
    private static string FindShortest(string input)
    {
        // all possible removable strings' indexes
        // for this given input
        int[] indexes = RemovableIndexes(input);

        // each input string and its possible removables are a state
        var state = new State { Input = input, Indexes = indexes };

        // create the tree
        GetChildren(state);

        // get the FIRST shortest
        // i.e. there would be more than one answer sometimes
        // this could be easily changed to get all possible results
        var result = 
            Descendants(state)
            .Where(d => d.Children == null || d.Children.Length == 0)
            .OrderBy(d => d.Input.Length)
            .FirstOrDefault().Input;


        return result;
    }

    // simple get all descendants of a node/state in a tree
    private static IEnumerable<State> Descendants(State root)
    {
        var states = new Stack<State>(new[] { root });
        while (states.Any())
        {
            State node = states.Pop();
            yield return node;
            if (node.Children != null)
                foreach (var n in node.Children) states.Push(n);
        }
    }

    // creates the tree
    private static void GetChildren(State state)
    {
        // for each an index there is a child
        state.Children = state.Indexes.Select(
                i =>
                {
                    var input = RemoveAllAt(state.Input, i);
                    return input.Length < state.Input.Length && input.Length > 0
                    ? new State
                    {
                        Input = input,
                        Indexes = RemovableIndexes(input)
                    }
                    : null;
                }).ToArray();

        foreach (var c in state.Children)
            GetChildren(c);
    }

    // find all possible removable strings' indexes
    private static int[] RemovableIndexes(string input)
    {
        var indexes = new List<int>();

        char d = input[0];
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (d == input[i])
                count++;
            else
            {
                if (count >= 3)
                    indexes.Add(i - count);

                // reset
                d = input[i];
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        if (count >= 3)
            indexes.Add(input.Length - count);


        return indexes.ToArray();
    }

    // remove all duplicate chars starting from an index
    private static string RemoveAllAt(string input, int startIndex)
    {
        string part1, part2;

        int endIndex = startIndex + 1;
        int i = endIndex;
        for (; i < input.Length; i++)
            if (input[i] != input[startIndex])
            {
                endIndex = i;
                break;
            }

        if (i == input.Length && input[i - 1] == input[startIndex])
            endIndex = input.Length;

        part1 = startIndex > 0 ? input.Substring(0, startIndex) : string.Empty;
        part2 = endIndex <= (input.Length - 1) ? input.Substring(endIndex) : string.Empty;

        return part1 + part2;
    }

    // our node, which is 
    // an input string & 
    // all possible removable strings' indexes
    // & its children
    public class State
    {
        public string Input;
        public int[] Indexes;

        public State[] Children;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the time and space complexity of this solution? (I mean the algorithm, not this particular implementation)

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I admit, I do not know how to compute it :). Hopefully someone will help! Still I think it is very simple/understandable solution.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, a question: why the code block in the answer is not recognized? i.e. I mean does not show colored keywords?

Comment: Please see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I don't know much about C# but the code seems to error with input `"abcccbcccbacccab"`. Also, this code seems to time-out for a 1000-character string on ideone.com.

Comment: @גלעדברקן it outputs `b` for `abcccbcccbacccab` and that's right

Comment: @Yola thanks - Ah yes it worked now. But how about "bcccbcccbaccca" :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן you can check it [here](http://rextester.com/FRTWMU7484) it works as well

Comment: @Yola huh! I don't know why the ideone was showing an error. Thanks!

Comment: @גלעדברקן you can try very simple test, just count number of times GetChildren gets called for string `AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC`, for me it **377** and it grows like exponentially. If you prepend the string with `AAABBB` then it is **4913**.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, the code I wrote in a bit of hurry just to show an example of the implementation of the algorithm, so for sure some bugs and low performance is there (the implementation) but the algorithm itself will get the correct answer(s) for sure, because it is an excessive tries for each possible path.

Comment: @Yola, thanks for the link! For sure this is not the smartest solution, or I would say this would produce the lowest performance ever, because it depends on an excessive tries for all possible paths.

Comment: Could you check your routine with `aaa`?

Comment: @Yola, again, it is just an implementation of the algorithm, which the OP is NOT looking for. Only the algorithm which each one can implement using his/her programming language and techniques. I thought of improving the implementation then I thought "What benefits it would bring and to whom?".

Comment: This is so beautiful I shed a tear.

Answer (score 3):

I propose O(n^2) solution with dynamic programming.

Let's introduce notation. Prefix and suffix of length l of string A denoted by P[l] and S[l]. And we call our procedure Rcd.

1. Rcd(A) = Rcd(Rcd(P[n-1])+S[1])
2. Rcd(A) = Rcd(P[1]+Rcd(S[n-1]))

Note that outer Rcd in the RHS is trivial. So, that's our optimal substructure. Based on this i came up with the following implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

string remdupright(string s, bool allowEmpty) {
    if (s.size() >= 3) {
        auto pos = s.find_last_not_of(s.back());
        if (pos == string::npos && allowEmpty) s = "";
        else if (pos != string::npos && s.size() - pos > 3) s = s.substr(0, pos + 1);
    }
    return s;
}

string remdupleft(string s, bool allowEmpty) {
    if (s.size() >= 3) {
        auto pos = s.find_first_not_of(s.front());
        if (pos == string::npos && allowEmpty) s = "";
        else if (pos != string::npos && pos >= 3) s = s.substr(pos);
    }
    return s;
}

string remdup(string s, bool allowEmpty) {
    return remdupleft(remdupright(s, allowEmpty), allowEmpty);
}

string run(const string in) {
    vector<vector<string>> table(in.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)table.size(); ++i) {
        table[i].resize(in.size() - i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)table[0].size(); ++i) {
        table[0][i] = in.substr(i,1);
    }

    for (int len = 2; len <= (int)table.size(); ++len) {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < (int)in.size() - len + 1; ++pos) {
            string base(table[len - 2][pos]);
            const char suffix = in[pos + len - 1];
            if (base.size() && suffix != base.back()) {
                base = remdupright(base, false);
            }
            const string opt1 = base + suffix;

            base = table[len - 2][pos+1];
            const char prefix = in[pos];
            if (base.size() && prefix != base.front()) {
                base = remdupleft(base, false);
            }
            const string opt2 = prefix + base;

            const string nodupopt1 = remdup(opt1, true);
            const string nodupopt2 = remdup(opt2, true);

            table[len - 1][pos] = nodupopt1.size() > nodupopt2.size() ? opt2 : opt1;
            assert(nodupopt1.size() != nodupopt2.size() || nodupopt1 == nodupopt2);
        }
    }
    string& res = table[in.size() - 1][0];
    return remdup(res, true);
}

void testRcd(string s, string expected) {
    cout << s << " : " << run(s) << ", expected: " << expected << endl;
}

int main()
{
    testRcd("BAABCCCBBA", "B");
    testRcd("AABBAAAC", "AABBC");
    testRcd("AAAA", "");
    testRcd("AAAABBBAC", "C");
}
```

You can check default and run your tests [here](http://rextester.com/LOHHL1807).

Comment: Seems to return AABC for AABBAAAC. As I understand it, the answer should be AABBC.

Comment: Are you sure your implementation is O(n^2)? Wouldn't then be able to fairly easily handle a 200-char string in the online IDE? (Like, `BCBCCBCCBCABBACCBABAABBBABBBACCBBBAABBACBCCCACABBCAABACBBBBCCCBBAACBAABACCBBCBBAABCCCCCAABBBBACBBAAACACCBCCBBBCCCCCCCACBABACCABBCBBBBBCBABABBACCAACBCBBAACBBBBBCCBABACBBABABAAABCCBBBAACBCACBAABAAAABABB`)

Comment: @גלעדברקן [here](http://rextester.com/HIF82244) test with another example from your code (you can run it), CPU time is 0.09 sec. The example from the last comment causes an error, so i will need to fix it in code.

Comment: Ah, awesome, it matches jdehesa's. I think this one also errs: `CBBACAAAAABBBBCAABBCBAABBBCBCBCACACBAABCBACBBABCABACCCCBACBCBBCBACBBACCCBAAAACACCABAACCACCBCBCABAACAABACBABACBCBAACACCBCBCCCABACABBCABBAAAAABBBBAABAABBCACACABBCBCBCACCCBABCAACBCAAAABCBCABACBABCABCBBBBABCBACABABABCCCBBCCBBCCBAAABCABBAAABBCAAABCCBAABAABCAACCCABBCAABCBCBCBBAACCBBBACBBBCABAABCABABABABCA`

Comment: It would be great if you could explain a little what the code is doing - how the algorithm is working.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yeh, that one also causes an error. I will try to find some time and fix my code plus write comments on Monday.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ok, the code is flawed, consider string `ACCCAAACBDDDBBBD` it can be reduced to `AB, AD, CB, CD`, so number of shortest possible strings is `2^(n/8)`. That's bad, because that could be only part of the string and we might need to choose some subset of them to continue. So, the algorithm doesn't work, but i will not delete it because i got +2 :D

Comment: Heh. I'd like to consider it, but I still don't understand what the code is doing, what the algorithm is :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן The main insight is in the beginning of the post. If you have string `ACCCAAACBDDDBBBD`  then you can find smallest possible string by considering smallest possible string for `prefix[0,n-1)` plus `D` and `A` plus `suffix[1,n)`. So, i store a table which first row consists of smallest strings of length 1 - `n` items, second row of smallest string of length 2 - `n-1` items, third row ... 3 - `n-2` and so on. But while storing you need to be careful not to delete extreme repeating characters from the left and from the right, to be able to contract them with new character.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thus as contraction for `CCCAAACBDDDBBBD` i store `CCCB` and when i add `A` from the left on the next level i store `AB`. And the problems arises when several minimal contraction are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly we are not concerned about any block of repeated characters longer than 2 characters. And there is only one way two blocks of the same character where at least one of the blocks is less than 3 in length can be combined - namely, if the sequence between them can be removed.

So (1) look at pairs of blocks of the same character where at least one is less than 3 in length, and (2) determine if the sequence between them can be removed.

We want to decide which pairs to join so as to minimize the total length of blocks less than 3 characters long. (Note that the number of pairs is bound by the size (and distribution) of the alphabet.)

Let `f(b)` represent the minimal total length of same-character blocks remaining up to the block `b` that are less than 3 characters in length. Then:

```
f(b):
  p1 <- previous block of the same character

  if b and p1 can combine:
    if b.length + p1.length > 2:
      f(b) = min(
        // don't combine
        (0 if b.length > 2 else b.length) +
          f(block before b),
        // combine
        f(block before p1)
      )

    // b.length + p1.length < 3
    else:
      p2 <- block previous to p1 of the same character

      if p1 and p2 can combine:
        f(b) = min(
          // don't combine
          b.length + f(block before b),
          // combine
          f(block before p2)
        )
      else:
        f(b) = b.length + f(block before b)

  // b and p1 cannot combine
  else:
    f(b) = b.length + f(block before b)

  for all p1 before b
```

The question is how can we efficiently determine if a block can be combined with the previous block of the same character (aside from the obvious recursion into the sub-block-list between the two blocks).

Python code:

```py
import random
import time

def parse(length):
  return length if length < 3 else 0

def f(string):
  chars = {}
  blocks = [[string[0], 1, 0]]

  chars[string[0]] = {'indexes': [0]}
  chars[string[0]][0] = {'prev': -1}

  p = 0 # pointer to current block

  for i in xrange(1, len(string)):
    if blocks[len(blocks) - 1][0] == string[i]:
      blocks[len(blocks) - 1][1] += 1
    else:
      p += 1
      # [char, length, index, f(i), temp] 
      blocks.append([string[i], 1, p])

      if string[i] in chars:
        chars[string[i]][p] = {'prev': chars[string[i]]['indexes'][ len(chars[string[i]]['indexes']) - 1 ]}
        chars[string[i]]['indexes'].append(p)
      else:
        chars[string[i]] = {'indexes': [p]}
        chars[string[i]][p] = {'prev': -1}

  #print blocks
  #print
  #print chars
  #print

  memo = [[None for j in xrange(len(blocks))] for i in xrange(len(blocks))]

  def g(l, r, top_level=False):
    ####
    ####
    #print "(l, r): (%s, %s)" % (l,r)

    if l == r:
      return parse(blocks[l][1])
    if memo[l][r]:
      return memo[l][r]

    result = [parse(blocks[l][1])] + [None for k in xrange(r - l)]

    if l < r:
      for i in xrange(l + 1, r + 1):
        result[i - l] = parse(blocks[i][1]) + result[i - l - 1]

    for i in xrange(l, r + 1):
      ####
      ####
      #print "\ni: %s" % i

      [char, length, index] = blocks[i]
      #p1 <- previous block of the same character
      p1_idx = chars[char][index]['prev']

      ####
      ####
      #print "(p1_idx, l, p1_idx >= l): (%s, %s, %s)" % (p1_idx, l, p1_idx >= l)

      if p1_idx < l and index > l:
        result[index - l] = parse(length) + result[index - l - 1]

      while p1_idx >= l:
        p1 = blocks[p1_idx]

        ####
        ####
        #print "(b, p1, p1_idx, l): (%s, %s, %s, %s)\n" % (blocks[i], p1, p1_idx, l)

        between = g(p1[2] + 1, index - 1)

        ####
        ####
        #print "between: %s" % between

        #if b and p1 can combine:
        if between == 0:
          if length + p1[1] > 2:
            result[index - l] = min(
              result[index - l],
              # don't combine
              parse(length) + (result[index - l - 1] if index - l > 0 else 0),
              # combine: f(block before p1)
              result[p1[2] - l - 1] if p1[2] > l else 0
            )

          # b.length + p1.length < 3
          else:
            #p2 <- block previous to p1 of the same character
            p2_idx = chars[char][p1[2]]['prev']

            if p2_idx < l:
              p1_idx = chars[char][p1_idx]['prev']
              continue

            between2 = g(p2_idx + 1, p1[2] - 1)
            #if p1 and p2 can combine:
            if between2 == 0:
              result[index - l] = min(
                result[index - l],
                # don't combine
                parse(length) + (result[index - l - 1] if index - l > 0 else 0),
                # combine the block, p1 and p2
                result[p2_idx - l - 1] if p2_idx - l > 0 else 0
              )
            else:
              #f(b) = b.length + f(block before b)
              result[index - l] = min(
                result[index - l],
                parse(length) + (result[index - l - 1] if index - l > 0 else 0)
              )

        # b and p1 cannot combine
        else:
          #f(b) = b.length + f(block before b)
          result[index - l] = min(
            result[index - l],
            parse(length) + (result[index - l - 1] if index - l > 0 else 0)
          )

        p1_idx = chars[char][p1_idx]['prev']

    #print l,r,result
    memo[l][r] = result[r - l]

    """if top_level:
      return (result, blocks)
    else:"""
    return result[r - l]

  if len(blocks) == 1:
    return ([parse(blocks[0][1])], blocks)
  else:
    return g(0, len(blocks) - 1, True)

"""s = ""

for i in xrange(300):
  s = s + ['A','B','C'][random.randint(0,2)]"""

print f("abcccbcccbacccab") # b
print
print f("AAAABBBAC");      # C
print
print f("CAAAABBBA");      # C
print
print f("AABBAAAC");      # AABBC
print
print f("BAABCCCBBA");    # B
print
print f("aaaa")
print
```

The string answers for these longer examples were computed using jdehesa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662885/remove-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-string-to-make-the-smallest-string/49690485#49690485):

```py
t0 = time.time()
print f("BCBCCBCCBCABBACCBABAABBBABBBACCBBBAABBACBCCCACABBCAABACBBBBCCCBBAACBAABACCBBCBBAABCCCCCAABBBBACBBAAACACCBCCBBBCCCCCCCACBABACCABBCBBBBBCBABABBACCAACBCBBAACBBBBBCCBABACBBABABAAABCCBBBAACBCACBAABAAAABABB")
# BCBCCBCCBCABBACCBABCCAABBACBACABBCAABACAACBAABACCBBCBBCACCBACBABACCABBCCBABABBACCAACBCBBAABABACBBABABBCCAACBCACBAABBABB
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print total

t0 = time.time()
print f("CBBACAAAAABBBBCAABBCBAABBBCBCBCACACBAABCBACBBABCABACCCCBACBCBBCBACBBACCCBAAAACACCABAACCACCBCBCABAACAABACBABACBCBAACACCBCBCCCABACABBCABBAAAAABBBBAABAABBCACACABBCBCBCACCCBABCAACBCAAAABCBCABACBABCABCBBBBABCBACABABABCCCBBCCBBCCBAAABCABBAAABBCAAABCCBAABAABCAACCCABBCAABCBCBCBBAACCBBBACBBBCABAABCABABABABCA")
# CBBACCAABBCBAACBCBCACACBAABCBACBBABCABABACBCBBCBACBBABCACCABAACCACCBCBCABAACAABACBABACBCBAACACCBCBABACABBCBBCACACABBCBCBCABABCAACBCBCBCABACBABCABCABCBACABABACCBBCCBBCACBCCBAABAABCBBCAABCBCBCBBAACCACCABAABCABABABABCA
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print total

t0 = time.time()
print f("AADBDBEBBBBCABCEBCDBBBBABABDCCBCEBABADDCABEEECCECCCADDACCEEAAACCABBECBAEDCEEBDDDBAAAECCBBCEECBAEBEEEECBEEBDACDDABEEABEEEECBABEDDABCDECDAABDAEADEECECEBCBDDAEEECCEEACCBBEACDDDDBDBCCAAECBEDAAAADBEADBAAECBDEACDEABABEBCABDCEEAABABABECDECADCEDAEEEBBBCEDECBCABDEDEBBBABABEEBDAEADBEDABCAEABCCBCCEDCBBEBCECCCA")
# AADBDBECABCEBCDABABDCCBCEBABADDCABCCEADDACCEECCABBECBAEDCEEBBECCBBCEECBAEBCBEEBDACDDABEEABCBABEDDABCDECDAABDAEADEECECEBCBDDACCEEACCBBEACBDBCCAAECBEDDBEADBAAECBDEACDEABABEBCABDCEEAABABABECDECADCEDACEDECBCABDEDEABABEEBDAEADBEDABCAEABCCBCCEDCBBEBCEA
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print total
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python solution (function `reduce_min`), not particularly smart but I think fairly easy to understand (excessive amount of comments added for answer clarity):

```py
def reductions(s, min_len):
    """
    Yields every possible reduction of s by eliminating contiguous blocks
    of l or more repeated characters.
    For example, reductions('AAABBCCCCBAAC', 3) yields
    'BBCCCCBAAC' and 'AAABBBAAC'.
    """
    # Current character
    curr = ''
    # Length of current block
    n = 0
    # Start position of current block
    idx = 0
    # For each character
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c != curr:
            # New block begins
            if n >= min_len:
                # If previous block was long enough
                # yield reduced string without it
                yield s[:idx] + s[i:]
            # Start new block
            curr = c
            n = 1
            idx = i
        else:
            # Still in the same block
            n += 1
    # Yield reduction without last block if it was long enough
    if n >= min_len:
        yield s[:idx]

def reduce_min(s, min_len):
    """
    Finds the smallest possible reduction of s by successive
    elimination of contiguous blocks of min_len or more repeated
    characters.
    """
    # Current set of possible reductions
    rs = set([s])
    # Current best solution
    result = s
    # While there are strings to reduce
    while rs:
        # Get one element
        r = rs.pop()
        # Find reductions
        r_red = list(reductions(r, min_len))
        # If no reductions are found it is irreducible
        if len(r_red) == 0 and len(r) < len(result):
            # Replace if shorter than current best
            result = r
        else:
            # Save reductions for next iterations
            rs.update(r_red)
    return result

assert reduce_min("BAABCCCBBA", 3) == "B"
assert reduce_min("AABBAAAC", 3) == "AABBC"
assert reduce_min("AAAA", 3) == ""
assert reduce_min("AAAABBBAC", 3) == "C"
```

---

*EDIT:* Since people seem to be posting C++ solutions, here is mine in C++ (again, function `reduce_min`):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void reductions(const string &s, unsigned int min_len, vector<string> &rs)
{
    char curr = '\0';
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned int idx = 0;
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (curr != *it)
        {
            auto i = distance(s.begin(), it);
            if (n >= min_len)
            {
                rs.push_back(s.substr(0, idx) + s.substr(i));
            }
            curr = *it;
            n = 1;
            idx = i;
        }
        else
        {
            n += 1;
        }
    }
    if (n >= min_len)
    {
        rs.push_back(s.substr(0, idx));
    }
}

string reduce_min(const string &s, unsigned int min_len)
{
    unordered_set<string> rs { s };
    string result = s;
    vector<string> rs_new;
    while (!rs.empty())
    {
        auto it = rs.begin();
        auto r = *it;
        rs.erase(it);
        rs_new.clear();
        reductions(r, min_len, rs_new);
        if (rs_new.empty() && r.size() < result.size())
        {
            result = move(r);
        }
        else
        {
            rs.insert(rs_new.begin(), rs_new.end());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(reduce_min("BAABCCCBBA", 3) == "B");
    assert(reduce_min("AABBAAAC", 3) == "AABBC");
    assert(reduce_min("AAAA", 3) == "");
    assert(reduce_min("AAAABBBAC", 3) == "C");
    return 0;
}
```

If you can use C++17 you can save memory by using [string views](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view).

---

*EDIT 2:* About the complexity of the algorithm. It is not straightforward to figure out, and as I said the algorithm is meant to be simple more than anything, but let's see. In the end, it is more or less the same as a breadth-first search. Let's say the string length is `n`, and, for generality, let's say the minimum block length (value 3 in the question) is `m`. In the first level, we can generate up to `n / m` reductions in the worst case. For each of these, we can generate up to `(n - m) / m` reductions, and so on. So basically, at "level" `i` (loop iteration `i`) we create up to `(n - i * m) / m` reductions per string we had, and each of these will take `O(n - i * m)` time to process. The maximum number of levels we can have is, again, `n / m`. So the complexity of the algorithm (if I'm not making mistakes) should have the form:

```
O( sum {i = 0 .. n / m} ( O(n - i * m) * prod {j = 0 .. i} ((n - i * m) / m) ))
       |-Outer iters--|   |---Cost---|        |-Prev lvl-| |---Branching---|
```

Whew. So this should be something like:

```
O( sum {i = 0 .. n / m} (n - i * m) * O(n^i / m^i) )
```

Which in turn would collapse to:

```
O((n / m)^(n / m))
```

So yeah, the algorithm is more or less simple, but it can run into exponential cost cases (the bad cases would be strings made entirely of exactly `m`-long blocks, like `AAABBBCCCAAACCC...` for `m` = 3).

Comment: For `abcccbcccbacccab` it returns vector with 3 elems `abbcccbacccab`,
`abcccbbacccab`,
`abcccbcccbaab`. While right answer is `b`.

Comment: @Yola No, it does return the right answer, but the function you have to call is `reduce_min`, not `reductions` (like `reduce_min("abcccbcccbacccab", 3)`). I've clarified it in the answer.

Comment: i'm having hard time calculating its complexity, you are research engineer why haven't you done this :) byt the way, code only answers are discouraged on SO

Comment: @Yola It is not a "code-only" answer, it has detailed explanations about the algorithm along with the code, as pointed out (in the Python version, I didn't repeat the explanations in C++). I have a lot of trouble understanding your answer, though. I didn't figure out the complexity (algorithmic complexity is not my speciality, if you want to know), it is indeed hard to do, and my answer was more intended to be a relatively simple one...

Comment: Sorry for bad news, that is exponential for certain strings. No good

Comment: @Yola Yes, I figured that out myself now and explained it in my answer. It's not very useful to make a claim about a (non-obvious) algorithm's complexity without further explanation (not that your other comments were very useful either, but whatever). Maybe if I can understand your answer at some point I'll upvote it, if that is what troubles you.

Comment: Surely, i want to get my answer upvoted, but that's no the reason why i comment here. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I was able to get the string answers for the examples at the end of my answer and compare results by running your code locally. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another scala answer, using memoization and tailcall optimization (partly) **(updated)**.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.annotation._

object StringCondense extends App {

  @tailrec
  def groupConsecutive (s: String, sofar: List[String]): List[String] = s.toList match {
  // def groupConsecutive (s: String): List[String] = s.toList match {
      case Nil => sofar
      // case Nil => Nil
      case c :: str => {
          val (prefix, rest) = (c :: str).span (_ == c)
          // Strings of equal characters, longer than 3, don't make a difference to just 3
          groupConsecutive (rest.mkString(""), (prefix.take (3)).mkString ("") :: sofar)
          // (prefix.take (3)).mkString ("") :: groupConsecutive (rest.mkString(""))
      }
  }
  // to count the effect of memoization
  var count = 0

// recursively try to eliminate every group of 3 or more, brute forcing
// but for "aabbaabbaaabbbaabb", many reductions will lead sooner or 
// later to the same result, so we try to detect these and avoid duplicate 
// work 

  def moreThan2consecutive (s: String, seenbefore: HashSet [String]): String = {
      if (seenbefore.contains (s)) s
      else
      {
        count += 1
        seenbefore += s
        val sublists = groupConsecutive (s, Nil)
        // val sublists = groupConsecutive (s)
        val atLeast3 = sublists.filter (_.size > 2)
        atLeast3.length match {
            case 0 => s
            case 1 => {
                val res = sublists.filter (_.size < 3)
                moreThan2consecutive (res.mkString (""), seenbefore)
            }
            case _ => {
                val shrinked = (
                    for {idx <- (0 until sublists.size)
                    if (sublists (idx).length >= 3)
                    pre = (sublists.take (idx)).mkString ("")
                    post= (sublists.drop (idx+1)).mkString ("")
                    } yield {
                        moreThan2consecutive (pre + post, seenbefore)
                    }
                )
                (shrinked.head /: shrinked.tail) ((a, b) => if (a.length <= b.length) a else b)
            }
        }
      }
  }

    // don't know what Rcd means, adopted from other solution but modified 
    // kind of a unit test **update**: forgot to reset count 
    testRcd (s: String, expected: String) : Boolean = {
        count = 0
        val seenbefore = HashSet [String] ()
        val result = moreThan2consecutive (s, seenbefore)
        val hit = result.equals (expected)
        println (s"Input: $s\t result: ${result}\t expected ${expected}\t $hit\t count: $count");
        hit
    }

    // some test values from other users with expected result
    // **upd:** more testcases
    def testgroup () : Unit = {
        testRcd ("baabcccbba", "b")
        testRcd ("aabbaaac", "aabbc")
        testRcd ("aaaa", "")
        testRcd ("aaaabbbac", "c")

        testRcd ("abcccbcccbacccab", "b")
        testRcd ("AAAABBBAC", "C")
        testRcd ("CAAAABBBA", "C")
        testRcd ("AABBAAAC", "AABBC")
        testRcd ("BAABCCCBBA", "B")

        testRcd ("AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC", "C")    // 377 subcalls reported by Yola,
        testRcd ("AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC", "C")  // 4913 when preceeded with AAABBB
    }
    testgroup

    def testBigs () : Unit = {
    /*
      testRcd ("BCBCCBCCBCABBACCBABAABBBABBBACCBBBAABBACBCCCACABBCAABACBBBBCCCBBAACBAABACCBBCBBAABCCCCCAABBBBACBBAAACACCBCCBBBCCCCCCCACBABACCABBCBBBBBCBABABBACCAACBCBBAACBBBBBCCBABACBBABABAAABCCBBBAACBCACBAABAAAABABB",
               "BCBCCBCCBCABBACCBABCCAABBACBACABBCAABACAACBAABACCBBCBBCACCBACBABACCABBCCBABABBACCAACBCBBAABABACBBABABBCCAACBCACBAABBABB")
    */
    testRcd ("CBBACAAAAABBBBCAABBCBAABBBCBCBCACACBAABCBACBBABCABACCCCBACBCBBCBACBBACCCBAAAACACCABAACCACCBCBCABAACAABACBABACBCBAACACCBCBCCCABACABBCABBAAAAABBBBAABAABBCACACABBCBCBCACCCBABCAACBCAAAABCBCABACBABCABCBBBBABCBACABABABCCCBBCCBBCCBAAABCABBAAABBCAAABCCBAABAABCAACCCABBCAABCBCBCBBAACCBBBACBBBCABAABCABABABABCA",
             "CBBACCAABBCBAACBCBCACACBAABCBACBBABCABABACBCBBCBACBBABCACCABAACCACCBCBCABAACAABACBABACBCBAACACCBCBABACABBCBBCACACABBCBCBCABABCAACBCBCBCABACBABCABCABCBACABABACCBBCCBBCACBCCBAABAABCBBCAABCBCBCBBAACCACCABAABCABABABABCA")
    /*testRcd ("AADBDBEBBBBCABCEBCDBBBBABABDCCBCEBABADDCABEEECCECCCADDACCEEAAACCABBECBAEDCEEBDDDBAAAECCBBCEECBAEBEEEECBEEBDACDDABEEABEEEECBABEDDABCDECDAABDAEADEECECEBCBDDAEEECCEEACCBBEACDDDDBDBCCAAECBEDAAAADBEADBAAECBDEACDEABABEBCABDCEEAABABABECDECADCEDAEEEBBBCEDECBCABDEDEBBBABABEEBDAEADBEDABCAEABCCBCCEDCBBEBCECCCA",
               "AADBDBECABCEBCDABABDCCBCEBABADDCABCCEADDACCEECCABBECBAEDCEEBBECCBBCEECBAEBCBEEBDACDDABEEABCBABEDDABCDECDAABDAEADEECECEBCBDDACCEEACCBBEACBDBCCAAECBEDDBEADBAAECBDEACDEABABEBCABDCEEAABABABECDECADCEDACEDECBCABDEDEABABEEBDAEADBEDABCAEABCCBCCEDCBBEBCEA")
    */
  }

  // for generated input, but with fixed seed, to compare the count with
    // and without memoization
    import util.Random
    val r = new Random (31415)

    // generate Strings but with high chances to produce some triples and 
    // longer sequences of char clones    
    def genRandomString () : String = {
      (1 to 20).map (_ => r.nextInt (6) match {
        case 0 => "t"
        case 1 => "r"
        case 2 => "-"
        case 3 => "tt"
        case 4 => "rr"
        case 5 => "--"
      }).mkString ("")
    }

    def testRandom () : Unit = {
      (1 to 10).map (i=> testRcd (genRandomString, "random mode - false might be true"))
    }

    testRandom

  testgroup
  testRandom
  // testBigs
}
```

Comparing the effect of memoization lead to interesting results:

**Updated** measurements. In the old values, I forgot to reset the counter, which leaded to much higher results. Now the spreading of results
is much more impressive and in total, the values are smaller.

```
No seenbefore:
Input: baabcccbba    result: b   expected b  true    count: 4
Input: aabbaaac      result: aabbc   expected aabbc  true    count: 2
Input: aaaa      result:     expected    true    count: 2
Input: aaaabbbac     result: c   expected c  true    count: 5
Input: abcccbcccbacccab  result: b   expected b  true    count: 34
Input: AAAABBBAC     result: C   expected C  true    count: 5
Input: CAAAABBBA     result: C   expected C  true    count: 5
Input: AABBAAAC      result: AABBC   expected AABBC  true    count: 2
Input: BAABCCCBBA    result: B   expected B  true    count: 4
Input: AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC  res: C   expected C  true    count: 377
Input: AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC r: C    expected C  true    count: 4913
Input: r--t----ttrrrrrr--tttrtttt--rr----result: rr--rr     expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 1959
Input: ttrtt----tr---rrrtttttttrtr--rr   result: r--rr      expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 213
Input: tt----r-----ttrr----ttrr-rr--rr-- result: ttrttrrttrr-rr--rr-- ex ? unknown ?     false   count: 16
Input: --rr---rrrrrrr-r--rr-r--tt--rrrrr result: rr-r--tt-- expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 32
Input: tt-rrrrr--r--tt--rrtrrr-------    result: ttr--tt--rrt   expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 35
Input: --t-ttt-ttt--rrrrrt-rrtrttrr  result: --tt-rrtrttrr  expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 35
Input: rrt--rrrr----trrr-rttttrrtttrr    result: rrtt-      expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 1310
Input: ---tttrrrrrttrrttrr---tt-----tt   result: rrttrr     expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 1011
Input: -rrtt--rrtt---t-r--r---rttr--     result: -rrtt--rr-r--rrttr-- ex ? unknown ?     false   count: 9
Input: rtttt--rrrrrrrt-rrttt--tt--t  result: r--t-rr--tt--t  expectd ? unknown ?     false   count: 16
real    0m0.607s    (without testBigs)
user    0m1.276s
sys 0m0.056s

With seenbefore:
Input: baabcccbba    result: b   expected b  true    count: 4
Input: aabbaaac      result: aabbc   expected aabbc  true    count: 2
Input: aaaa      result:     expected    true    count: 2
Input: aaaabbbac     result: c   expected c  true    count: 5
Input: abcccbcccbacccab  result: b   expected b  true    count: 11
Input: AAAABBBAC     result: C   expected C  true    count: 5
Input: CAAAABBBA     result: C   expected C  true    count: 5
Input: AABBAAAC      result: AABBC   expected AABBC  true    count: 2
Input: BAABCCCBBA    result: B   expected B  true    count: 4
Input: AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC rest: C   expected C  true    count: 28
Input: AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBC C   expected C  true    count: 52
Input: r--t----ttrrrrrr--tttrtttt--rr----result: rr--rr     expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 63
Input: ttrtt----tr---rrrtttttttrtr--rr   result: r--rr      expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 48
Input: tt----r-----ttrr----ttrr-rr--rr-- result: ttrttrrttrr-rr--rr-- xpe? unknown ?     false   count: 8
Input: --rr---rrrrrrr-r--rr-r--tt--rrrrr result: rr-r--tt-- expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 19
Input: tt-rrrrr--r--tt--rrtrrr-------    result: ttr--tt--rrt   expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 12
Input: --t-ttt-ttt--rrrrrt-rrtrttrr  result: --tt-rrtrttrr  expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 16
Input: rrt--rrrr----trrr-rttttrrtttrr    result: rrtt-      expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 133
Input: ---tttrrrrrttrrttrr---tt-----tt   result: rrttrr     expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 89
Input: -rrtt--rrtt---t-r--r---rttr--     result: -rrtt--rr-r--rrttr-- ex ? unknown ?     false   count: 6
Input: rtttt--rrrrrrrt-rrttt--tt--t  result: r--t-rr--tt--t expected ? unknown ?     false   count: 8
real    0m0.474s    (without testBigs)
user    0m0.852s
sys 0m0.060s

With tailcall:
real    0m0.478s    (without testBigs)
user    0m0.860s
sys 0m0.060s
```

For some random strings, the difference is bigger than a 10fold.

For long Strings with many groups one could, as an improvement, eliminate all groups which are the only group of that character, for instance:

```
aa bbb aa ccc xx ddd aa eee aa fff xx
```

The groups bbb, ccc, ddd, eee and fff are unique in the string, so they can't fit to something else and could all be eliminated, and the order of removal is will not matter. This would lead to the intermediate result

```
aaaa xx aaaa xx
```

and a fast solution. Maybe I try to implement it too. However, I guess, it will be possible to produce random Strings, where this will have a big impact and by a different form of random generated strings, to distributions, where the impact is low.